# adding to StringListProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tags, tagging

i have the following

```
 class Image(db.Model):
    author = db.UserProperty()
    img = db.BlobProperty()
    rating = db.RatingProperty()
    tags = db.ListProperty()
```

when the user upload an image , he will enter a list of tags by is choose sperating by comma
so how can I store them in the database using the StringListProperty or ListProperty ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to split the string.

An example:

```
tags = self.request.get('tags').split(',')
img_ref.tags.extend(tags)
img_ref.put()
```

Comment: great thanks this is the first time I develop in python , btw using extends ?